# How to get Spring Boot session attributes several request layers down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session-cookies, spring-session

Is there a way to get request.request.request.session.attributes as seen in the hierarchy in the image? I have tried the following:

[image]

`Object value = request.getAttribute("Travis");`

and

`Object value2 = request.getSession().getAttribute("Travis");`

However, both return null. I have confirmed the session Id is correct.

Is there a way to grab values from the request this deep down?

Comment: The first will fail as that is getting the request attributes. The second is the way to do it. If it doesn't you are doing something weird or the name doesn't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the data by using the HazelcastHttpSession. HazelcastHttpSession session.

`Object value = session.getOriginalSession().getAttribute("Travis");`

Answer (score -1):

You can access session directly with `HttpSession`:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

// for instance
@GetMapping("test")
public void test(HttpSession session) {
  session.getAttribute("Travis");
}
```

Comment: This comes back null as well.